# Neural Network Output if some outputs blocked

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm building a neural network for the board game Checkers and I've hit a massive block I don't know how to get around.

I've built my neural network in Java, using a genetic algorithm to adjust the weights, but the question/problem is how do I make the output only output moves that are acceptable?

In checkers, depending on a piece's location and the other adjacent pieces, some moves are blocked and therefore cannot be an output for my NN. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you’re using a genetic algorithm either put a penalty for impossible moves or just set the fitness to zero if the move is impossible. On the output of the NN check if the move is valid and select the highest valid move.